# Вывод элементов односвязного списка

Tags: c, структуры-данных, односвязный-список

Здравствуйте :)

Есть проблемка: при выводе списка заказчиков, перед их удалением, если я удаляю последнего заказчика и потом пытаюсь вывести список заказчиков на экран,
то в выводится мусор, а на строке 6 ошибка (Segmentation fault) и тут возникает вопрос:
как проверить пустой у меня список или нет?

```
 void DisplayList(PCust Head) {
    PCust current = Head;

    printf("--- Spisok vseh pokupatelei ---\n");
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", current->fio);
        current = current->next;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Функция удаления узла:

```
void DeleteNode(PCust *Head, PCust p)
{
    PCust q = *Head;

    if(*Head == p)          // Особый случай, если голова списка совпадает с удаляемым узлом
        Head = &(p->next);  // нужно поменять голову списка. Голова списка смещается на адрес следующего узла
    else{
        while(q && q->next != p)    // пока не находим предыдущий узел до удаляемого (p)
            q = q->next;            // делаем проход по списку
        if(q == NULL) return;
        q->next = p->next;          // если мы нашли узел перед удаляемым, переставляем ссылку ->next c узла перед удаляемым на следующий узел после удаляемого.
    }
    free(p); // освобождаем память под тот узел, который нам надо удалить.
}
```

Comment: А когда вы удаляете последний оставшийся элемент списка, вы указатель обнуляете?

Comment: Нет. Сейчас добавлю функцию удаления узла в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум, очень странное действие:

```
Head = &(p->next);
```

Правильно

```
*Head = p->next;
```

Указатель `Head` должен указывать туда, куда указывал `p->next`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Помогло